# SQL Server cast to text datatype

Tags: php, sql-server, t-sql

Can someone help me with SQL Server `CAST` to `text` datatype? I'm trying to get the long text to display using the CAST function, but it wont work if I am retrieving from more than 1 table. Perhaps I've created the statement incorrectly.

```
$from = 'RealEstate AS RE, Models AS M, Catalogue AS C';

$select = 'CAST(RE.Details AS TEXT) AS RE.Details, RE.Postcode, RE.Suburb, 
    M.ModelName, M.ModelID, RE.HouseID, RE.ContactName, RE.ContactPhone, RE.PlanName, 
    RE.Address, RE.Street, RE.Price, RE.StreetNo, RE.CatID, RE.Fixed';


$query = mssql_query("SELECT DISTINCT $select 
                      FROM RealEstate AS RE, Models AS M 
                      WHERE RE.HouseID=$hid 
                      AND RE.ModelID=M.ModelID");
```

Comment: What specifically is the error message you are getting? And why exactly are you converting to text? It's not like it will increase the number of characters stored already. And please learn to use explicit joins, implicit joins are prone to errors, harder to maintain and are very poor coding techinique.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you can not concatenate strings within the mssql_query block - I don't see the need for it really, based on what you provided.  If you want to concatenate a dynamic SQL statement, do it as such before sending the statement to the `mssql_query` function:

```
$select = 'SELECT DISTINCT CAST(re.details AS TEXT) as details,
                                         re.postcode,
                                         re.suburb,
                                         m.modelname,
                                         m.modelid,
                                         re.houseid,
                                         re.contactname,
                                         re.contactphone,
                                         re.planname,
                                         re.address,
                                         re.street,
                                         re.price,
                                         re.streetno,
                                         re.catid,
                                         re.fixed
                               FROM REALESTATE re
                               JOIN MODELS m ON m.modelid = re.modelid
                              WHERE re.houseid = $hid"
$query = mssql_query($select);
```

Comment: @Honshi: Table names are not case sensitive, uppercase is just my coding style.  Without failure details, I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure aliases can't contain a period (offender: `RE.Details`). Try calling it `Details` instead (or enclose the alias in quotes (backticks for mysql) if you want to keep the period, but I'm guessing you don't).

Comment: both the $from table Model and RealEstate carries the same "Details" field. That's why I used the period to call only the Details from the RealEstate table.

you're right about taking out the period. It works but then again in a single table, there's no need for me to do the RealEstate AS RE call.

I can however make this into a double query, but i just want to try to make it as short as possible.

Comment: @Honshi: Not for the column alias - see my query as an example.  If you really need to see a column named "re.details", backticks only work for MySQL - the ANSI standard is to use double quotes.

Comment: @OMG Ponies I'm trying out your code. still not working. I thought the tables are case-sensitive? so i converted all the codes to the right case but still not working. thanks for your suggestion though

Comment: Sorry, misread the question and thought it was MySQL. Changed it to say "quotes" instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$queryDetails = mssql_query("SELECT CAST(Details AS TEXT) AS Details FROM RealEstate WHERE HouseID=$hid");
```

I made another query from it. Its probably a redundant call. I'm more familiar with mySQL, after using msSQL i realize that it is quite troublesome to manipulate it. especially when the LIMIT function is not available for pagination.